# Conditionally reuse a `hasOne` association multiple times inside the same query

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

## What I have

In my `OrdersTable.php`:

```
$this->hasOne('Total', [
    'className' => 'App\Model\Table\TotalsTable',
    'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
    'propertyName' => 'Total'
]);
```

Actual `totals` table:

```
| id | order_id |     type | value |
|----|----------|----------|-------|
|  1 |        1 |    total |   100 |
|  2 |        1 |      tax |    20 |
|  3 |        1 | shipping |     5 |
```

The structure and logic come from [opencart/opencart](https://github.com/opencart/opencart) and I have no control over that.

## What I want

This is a non-functional concept:

```
$query = $ordersTable->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'TotalTax' => [
            'associationName' => 'Total',
            'conditions' => function($query) {
                return $query->where([
                    'TotalTax.type' => 'tax',
                ]);
            },
        ],
        'TotalShipping' => [
            'associationName' => 'Total',
            'conditions' => function($query) {
                return $query->where([
                    'TotalShipping.type' => 'shipping',
                ]);
            },
        ],
    ),
));
```

Do you guys think something like this is possible?

**UPD**: Creating an association for each `type` isn't an option since there may be too many of them

Comment: Have you considered adding separate associations for TotalTax and TotalShipping? That would certainly work, lots of examples here and elsewhere of how to set that up.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, thank you for your input. This question lists only 2 options (tax and shipping), but there may be much more associations I may need in another scenario, such as linking stores to their settings. This is why I specifically asked about reusing an existing association, instead of defining new ones.

Comment: Let's make it quick, the answer is no, it's not possible, at least not out of the box. Surely you could do something like overwrite `Table::contain()` and create associations on the fly with the given configuration, and pass on a proper containment array, but I fail to see how specifying these containments over over and over again would be an advantage over creating all associations initially. Maybe you should instead elaborate on the underlying problem that you are trying to solve!? What is the _technical need_ for having individual columns as separate associations in the first place?

Comment: Why aren't you simply calculating and saving the totals on save to the orders table?

Comment: @burzum *The structure and logic come from opencart/opencart and I have no control over that*

Answer (score 0):

If this functionality is something that will be reused with your codebase, I would implement this logic at the table level and have two different conditional associations:

In `OrdersTable.php`

```
$this->hasOne('TotalTax', [
            'className' => 'Totals'
        ])
        ->setConditions(['TotalTax.type' => 'tax'])
        ->setDependent(true);

$this->hasOne('TotalShipping', [
            'className' => 'Totals'
        ])
        ->setConditions(['TotalShipping.type' => 'shipping'])
        ->setDependent(true);
```

Then you can simply contain them in the query:

```
$query = $ordersTable->find()->contain(['TotalTax', 'TotalShipping'];
```

An example of this can be found in the [CakePHP documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)

Comment: Thanks but [I already declined a similar suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989380/conditionally-reuse-a-hasone-association-multiple-times-inside-the-same-query#comment90934749_51989380)

Comment: Why isn't this an option?